# SignalR vs custom TCP - pros and cons

Tags: c#, asp.net, tcp, signalr

What are the real benefits and drawbacks of using SignalR when compared to a custom TCP implementation (in C#)?

I have found many comparisons of SignalR vs other HTTP-based frameworks, but I could not get any on SignalR vs custom TCP server implementation. I understand, there will be much more work on designing custome TCP, because all of the protocols, handshakes and so on. But what about connection state, speed, connection IDs, connected users and groups?

Moreover, when do the drawbacks of SignalR outweight the benefits, so a custom TCP is required? What about services, game servers (real-time vs turn-based games), and so on? I know, this question is quite broad, but I would really appreciate a complex answer on the pros and cons of using SignalR over custom implementation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You figure out about this with http://xsockets.net/xsockets-vs-signalr.

Comment: That is not exactly what I was looking for. XSockets is an already implemented (and paid) solution. I was looking for a comparison with custom implementation of TCP communication from the scratch (i.e. I would have to implement it).